# Сборка проекта под макос

Tags: android-sdk, android, macos

Перенес свои проекты с винды на мак (проекты рабочие). Поставил яву эклипс ант сдк и прочее. Пытаюсь собрать проект и генерируются только папки classes  и res в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

В бубен били? (Fix project properties, Clean .., "`chown -R ваш_юзверь:ваш_юзверь каталог_прокта/`")

Comment: Да. Права на чтение и запись стоят.